Unable to load MongoDB atlas data via pyspark jdbc in Glue
I am trying to load the MongoDB Atlas data using the Pyspark native way in AWS Glue. I can connect to the DB via the Ec2 instance and see the data there.
Versions:

MongoDB: 5.0.26
JAR: mongo-spark-connector_2.13-10.3.0.jar

I have also included the path of this JAR in the dependent-jars-file path in Glue job settings. Below is my code:
df = (
            self.spark.read.format("mongodb")
            .option(
                "connection.uri",
                "mongodb+srv://<something>.<some-thing>.mongodb.net/<db>?authSource=<user>",
            )
            .option("collection", "")
            .load()
            .limit(5)
        )  

But it gives me the below error:
Error Category: UNCLASSIFIED_ERROR; An error occurred while calling o116.showString. Invalid field: 'metadata.dateButtonInstalled'. The dataType 'timestamp' is invalid for 'BsonString{value='2018-07-25T21:47:23.195Z'}'.

I have checked and tested for other collections and it works fine. I can't change the source data. So any configs that I can use?
I also tried with the sampleSize property by passing lower to higher values but every time it gives an error on different fields.

Can you please specify which line in your code is raising this error?

@ParmanM.Alizadeh When I try to do .show() on df
